# Using tmux loses all my bash aliases, how can I get them to stay?

Tags: bash, rvm, alias, tmux

My .bashrc does

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

which includes runs my `.bash_aliases` and gives me a ton of aliases that I've defined.

However if I try and use TMUX (invoked with `tmux`) the only alias I now have is:

`$ alias`<kbd>return</kbd> # will show....

```
$ alias rvm-restart='rvm_reload_flag=1 source '\''/home/durrantm/.rvm/scripts/rvm'\'''
```

How can I use tmux and still have all my aliases available.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04

The end of my .bashrc file looks like this:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# Automatic cd'ing
shopt -s autocd

if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM

export EDITOR=vim

git config --global --add color.ui true
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

tmux invokes your shell as a login shell. Login shells don't process `.bashrc`, but use `.bash_profile` instead.

You can simply make `.bash_profile` read your `.bashrc`:

```
echo 'source ~/.bashrc' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following setting to `~/.tmux.conf` (s. [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38475/392931)):

```
set-option -g default-command $SHELL
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better simply run `bash` in tmux once the pane is "started". There is a difference btw login and interactive shells for a reason.
I would rather search for a way to run a command in every newly created pane.

Comment: Please help me understand why it is better and what the reasons are for the two shells that lead to this advice.  For years I've had bash start tmux automatically and it hasn't been a problem or affected login shells do I'd like to learn more specifics, thanks.